# Problem with distributed Computing with mdf files

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, compact-database, ssms

I am using SQL EXPRESS EDITION 2005 and  Created mdf data file using vb.net 2008. now i want to use this datafile in lan. i modified connection string

"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\Server\Data\Data1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Connect Timeout=60"

it is showing security info error i want to use single database file for my application please help me with connection string. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possibilities...

One, invalid path in your connection string.
Change your path:
From:  \Server\Data\Data1.mdf
To: \\Server\Data\Data1.mdf  (notice the extra backslash at the beginning)

Two, your SQL isn't set up to accept remote connections:

> Open the configuration tools, and then
>   click the SQL Server Network
>   Configuration, Click Protocols for SQL
>   Express. Then enable the Shared Memory
>   if not (by default it will be
>   enabled), Named Pipes and TCP/IP and
>   restart the Server.  And ensure that
>   your firewall is allowing the remote
>   connections to SQL Server.

Comment: What should be Data source .\SQLEXPRESS or SERVER\\SQLEXPRESS Can you please give me possible connection string thanks

Comment: @Rohan - it would be SERVER\SQLEXPRESS. www.connectionstrings.com has an excellent page on SQL Server 2008 connection strings [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008).